# How to Inherit Class property in CSHTML file for Text box and Button in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4 with Entity Framework. I need to inherit property for the text box and button in cshtml file. And also i have to assign the text box value with Model. Please help me to get the property. Thanks in advance.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control uname" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" class="form-control pword" placeholder="Password" />
                    <a href="#"><small>Forgot Your Password?</small></a>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign In</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one....

```
@Model your model.


@using (Html.BeginForm("YOUR_ACTION", "YOUR_Controller"))
{
<fieldset>
<div class="form-control uname">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)</div>
<div class="form-control uname">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)</div>

<div class="form-control pword">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password).</div>
<div class="form-control pword">@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)</div>
<br/>
</fieldset>
<a href="#"><small>Forgot Your Password?</small></a>
<input type="Submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
             @model SomeModel

             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {class="form-control uname",placeholder="Username" />
             <input type="password" class="form-control pword" placeholder="Password" />
             <a href="#"><small>Forgot Your Password?</small></a>
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign In</button>
```

Inherit the model & then apply the html elements with the values of the model.

Answer (score 1):

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {class="form-control uname",placeholder="Username" />
 @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.UserPAssword, new { class="style class name", placeholder="Password"/>